# AWS redshift alter table with default string

Tags: amazon-redshift, alter-table

I am testing the alter command in AWS Redshift. I have created a test_table_sort table to which I am trying to add a column called school.

```
create table test_table_sort (
  id int generated by default as identity (1,3) not null,
  student_name varchar(50),
  primary key(id))
 sortkey (student_name);
```

I have added some student ids and name. Now I've altered by adding and age column

```
alter table test_table_sort add column age int default 10
```

But when I try to add a varchar column as `alter table test_table_sort add column school varchar(30) default "SVS school"`  the system throws an error as below

**ERROR: column "svs school" does not exist in test_table_sort** .
I've first thought there may be some spacing error or something like that but not sure what is the problem with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is with a quote's format

`""` is used for accessing a column's name

try

```sql
alter table test_table_sort add column school varchar(30) default 'SVS school'
```